# XAMPP: Error 404 Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server when calling APIs

Tags: php, apache, xampp, slim

I'm using xampp in Windows 10 to run slimframework that calls API when logging in.

If I type the localhost/maps.html, the site can be accessed but if I try to click the login button in index.html, the Login API is not called.

I already configured the `httpd` and `httpd-vhosts`, the site can be accessed locally but whenever I tried clicking the login button in index.html, this error message appeared:

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.7
```

Here is what my directory structure looks like:

Under root folder:

```
-index.php
-maps.html
-index.html
-admin/
-js/
-vendor/
-.htaccess
```

Inside index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Maps</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1 data-bind="text:site_title"></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="login_container">
    <div id="login_view">
      <div>
        <input id="loginid" type="text" data-bind="value: loginid, event:{keypress:kpLoginId}" placeholder="LoginID" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="password" type="password" data-bind="value: password, event:{keypress:kpPassword}" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button id="login" data-bind="click: login">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="visible: failed">
    Cannot Login
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myslimsite\web_src"
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myslimsite\web_src">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>
```

Inside .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Is there any additional setup that needs to be configured aside from httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf to make the other page work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

This is not how Slim works. You have to add an internal redirect to the "front-controller". The front-controller is the index.php file. Then you define the routes in Slim and not within the `.htaccess` file.

Please read the documentation first:

- https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#apache-configuration
- https://github.com/selective-php/basepath#installation